# Using StateMachineFactory from PersistHandlerConfig

Tags: spring-statemachine

We are doing a POC with SSM using PersistHandlerConfig (Persist recipe).
It looks good, but some other questions appeared.

Since it needs to be a multi user webapp with a single instance per user, we was trying to follow the StateMachineFactory recommendation and changing the code but the recipe for Persistence looks not ready to handle this case.

There's a way to get the required statetemachine (from its sm id) within PersistHandlerConfig?

```
@Configuration
public class PersistHandlerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private StateMachineFactory<Tasks, Events> statemachinefactory;

    @Bean
    public Persist persist() {
        return new Persist(persistStateMachineHandler());
    }

    // Here is the problem, since this instance should be the one is in use
    // it should be instantiated with the sm id currently activating the persistence
    @Bean
    public PersistStateMachineHandler persistStateMachineHandler() {
        return new PersistStateMachineHandler(statemachinefactory.getStateMachine());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things get a bit tricky in this case for webapp and multiple users. `Scope` sample shows howto use machine as session scoped bean(one machine per user) and `Eventservice` shows how to user one machine per request where machines are pooled(reused per request).

It depends on how many users you have as ssm is relatively heavy component so reusing a machine is good idea on those cases. Also you may get into trouble with session scoped beans as ssm is not serializable. Spring stores session scoped bean in a `HttpSession` which i.e. tomcat may try to persist for clustered server.

Comment: So we have to build an application that may get thousands of requests per second. The Order object with multiple states is analogous to our domain object. Hence we are evaluating SSM for it. As per your comment does it mean that it would be tricky to handle 1000s of parallel requests due to performance and memory issues as ssm is a heavy component?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for my multi user environment. The recipes concept does not really work. Using just one state machine for all requests is not thread safe. I wrote my own class in style of the PersistStateMachineHandler, but not with a given StateMachine but with a given StateMachineFactory.

```
public class PersistentStateMachineHandler<S, T> {
    private final StateMachineFactory<S, T> stateMachineFactory;
    private final PersistingStateChangeInterceptor<S, T> interceptor = new PersistingStateChangeInterceptor<>();
    private final CompositePersistStateChangeListener<S, T> listeners = new CompositePersistStateChangeListener<>();

    public PersistentStateMachineHandler(StateMachineFactory<S, T> stateMachineFactory) {
        this.stateMachineFactory = stateMachineFactory;
    }

    public void addPersistentStateChangeListener(PersistentStateChangeListener<S, T> persistentStateChangeListener) {
        listeners.register(persistentStateChangeListener);
    }

    public boolean handleEventWithState(Map<Object, Object> variables, S state, T event) {
        StateMachine<S, T> stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine();
        stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(function -> function.addStateMachineInterceptor(interceptor));
        if (state == null) {
            state = stateMachine.getInitialState().getId();
        }
        ExtendedState extendedState = new DefaultExtendedState(variables);
        List<StateMachineAccess<S, T>> withAllRegions = stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().withAllRegions();
        for (StateMachineAccess<S, T> a : withAllRegions) {
            a.resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<S, T>(state, null, null, extendedState));
        }
        stateMachine.start();
        return stateMachine.sendEvent(event);
    }

    public interface PersistentStateChangeListener<S, T> {
        void persist(State<S, T> state, Message<T> message, Transition<S, T> transition, StateMachine<S, T> stateMachine);
    }

    private class PersistingStateChangeInterceptor<X, Y> extends StateMachineInterceptorAdapter<S, T> {
        @Override
        public void preStateChange(State<S, T> state, Message<T> message, Transition<S, T> transition, StateMachine<S, T> stateMachine) {
            listeners.persist(state, message, transition, stateMachine);
        }
    }

    private class CompositePersistStateChangeListener<X, Y> extends AbstractCompositeListener<PersistentStateChangeListener<S, T>> implements
        PersistentStateChangeListener<S, T> {

        @Override
        public void persist(State<S, T> state, Message<T> message, Transition<S, T> transition, StateMachine<S, T> stateMachine) {
        for (Iterator<PersistentStateChangeListener<S, T>> iterator = getListeners().reverse(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            PersistentStateChangeListener<S, T> listener = iterator.next();
            listener.persist(state, message, transition, stateMachine);
        }
    }
}
```

}

There are two other advantages in my implementation compared to the recipes implementation in spring.

1. This implementation can be used with enums and not only with Strings
2. The implementation can be used with state machines which trigger a state change by a timer, because the state is not carried in the message of the event but it uses the extendedState of the state machine itself.

For sure, for each event a new state machine is created, but I found not way to determine, if an existing state machine is still active (e.g. asynchronous tasks runs, timer runs). If one can find a way to determine this, a pool of state machines can be used instead.